# install rev on mingw using mingw-apt-get

Tags: linux, mingw

is there a way to install rev command on mingw, couldn't find it as a package.
I need to use rev on mingw under windows.  or do I need to resort to cygwin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get it [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/util-linux-ng.htm) if you want to execute it from cmd.exe

MSYS doesn't have rev (or I couldn't find where they put it). A full MSYS package (with *everything*) can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/External%20binary%20packages%20%28Win64%20hosted%29/MSYS%20%2832-bit%29/). I haven't checked if it's in there or not. If it's not, there is no MSYS "rev".

Answer (score 1):

`rev` is part of the `util-linux` package, at least on my Ubuntu system. If MinGW has a `util-linux` package, you should install that.

Comment: It doesn't have such package